# Counting a char in String

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'd like to know how can I count number of `l`s in string `Hello`?
Any help will be really appreciated.

```
public int countChar(String s, char c)
{   
    String st= s;
    char ch =c;
    int counter = 0;
    for( int i=0; i<st.length(); i++ )
    {
        if( st.charAt(i) == ch ) 
        {
            counter++;
        } 
    }       
    return counter;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    new Loop().countChar("Hello", 'l');         
}
```

Comment: The answer is 2. :) Anyway, what specifically isn't working about this code?

Comment: So what's the problem with the code you posted? :)

Comment: If you're wondering why nothing is printing to the console, you aren't printing anything to the console (`System.out.println`).

Comment: my apologies I wasn't clear in my question.So,I can't see what's wrong with this code but it's not returning any value.

Comment: Thanks all. I have a test tomorrow and I'm overwhelmed that's why I didn't realize that i didn't print the output.

Answer (score 2):

This should be working as you expect - if you want to print the result, change the `main` to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    int count = new Loop().countChar("Hello", 'l');
    System.out.println("The count is: " + count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code:

public class CharacterCout {

```
public static int getCharacterCount(String string, char character) {
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++) {
        if(string.charAt(i)==character){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "Hello World!";
    char character = 'l';
    System.out.println("Character "+character+" count: " +getCharacterCount(string, character));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public String twoOccurrences(String stringa, char stringb) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringa.length(); i++) {
        if (stringa.charAt(i) == stringb) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter >= 1) {
        return "" + counter;
    } else {
        return "There is no matching letters";
    }
}

public void testOcurrences() {
    char stringb = 'a';
    String stringa = "Banana";
    System.out.println("String a is :" + stringa);
    System.out.println("String b is :" + stringb);
    String occurrence = twoOccurrences(stringa, stringb);
    System.out.println("There is " + occurrence + " '" + stringb + "' in " + stringa);
}
```

}